# Reasking questions after closing as duplicate

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Some days ago I came across these two questions:

- [Trying to render to several textures to implement deferred rendering. But all textures are equal to the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640578/trying-to-render-to-several-textures-to-implement-deferred-rendering-but-all-te)
- [Trying to render to several textures to implement deferred rendering. But all textures are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642071/trying-to-render-to-several-textures-to-implement-deferred-rendering-but-all-te)

Both were asked by the same user in a very short timeframe. It seems that the first question was closed as a duplicate with which the user didn't agree (as stated in the second question – stating this is the only change to the question actually). I flagged the first (duplicate) question for moderator attention with the following text:

> Should be deleted since op reasked the question, stating that the duplicate wasn't the same problem.

My flag was declined as "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". I'm now wondering what would have been the right way to go for such questions. For me (and most probably the OP), closing the first question as a duplicate seemed wrong since it didn't solve the problem and now the question is misleading for other users with the same problem. Just leaving this question on the site feels somehow wrong to me.

What is the correct way to handle such questions?

Comment: Just vote to close it as duplicate.

Comment: @cerbrus: Thanks for your reply. That the first question is closed as a duplicate is my concern. The second one is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: The banner on a duplicate question tells the OP what to do if they feel like the question is not a duplicate: **edit** the question to add more information that makes it not a duplicate. It will then go into the reopen queue.

Comment: Weird duplicate closure that. I'm not the world's greatest expert on OpenGL, but I see no relation between the source and the dupe target except both being about OpenGL. But the repeat question most definitely is a dupe.

Comment: @Gimby: Yes, thats what I also thought. But in the state both questions are now, the best option would in my opinion be to remove the first question or to retarget the duplicate to the second question. The first option got already declined and I can't do the retargeting. That's why I posted here.

Comment: I don't know what should be done that makes it less of a mess. The repeat question is definitely better, and answered already. Time to just let it go, maybe.